# Javascript functions synchronous vs asynchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-sql

I have a webSQL database that I'm querying a good bit on pageshow/deviceready.

If I call my functions inside a pageshow like so:

```
$('#home').on('pageshow', function() {

request();
another();
morestill();

});
```

Will they be called and complete sequentially before the next one is started? Or do they happen asynchronously? I was wondering how this might affect performance? Would I be better to call the next function inside and at the end of the previous function rather than use the above? Or does this make no difference to performance?

Sorry if this is a stupid question!

Comment: Whats these function do?  `request, another` the answer for question `Will they be called and complete sequentially before the next one is started?` will depend on that

Comment: They will wait for the previous one done to start unless you dont have timers inside.

Comment: The three functions will be called in order. However, if they each make an asynchronous call they will complete in the order that the calls are satisfied. This could be any order. The best way to structure this will depend on your required outcome.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use webSQL? Seems like it wont be a W3C standard. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database

Comment: @Mathias webSQL is the only real viable option for client side storage using phonegap/cordova on iOS at the moment - at least as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

The WebSQL specification defines [an asynchronous database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#asynchronous-database-api) and [a synchronous database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#synchronous-database-api).

If you use the synchronous API (and don't do anything else to make the function call asynchronous) then they will run sequentially.

If you use the asynchronous API, then the various bits of the three function calls will be interleaved.

Answer (score -1):

The tree request are made synchronously, so before calling the next function the function before must be ended. If the request function must wait for a response of the server this time will be wasted